# Construct a random walk on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Construct a random walk on $\mathbb{R}$ such that it is returnable and the set of its values is everywhere dense in  $\mathbb{R}$.

I think that random walk $S_{n} = \xi_{1} + ... + \xi_{n}$, where random variable $\xi$ with values $\frac{1}{n}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \neq 0 $ and $P(\xi = \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{p(1-p)^{n-1}}{2} , P(\xi = -\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{p(1-p)^{n-1}}{2}$, could be the solution of this task. But I don't know how to prove that it's returnable.

Comment: When you say returnable, do you mean that it returns to $0$ almost surely?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur, random walk $S_{n}$ is returnable if $P((\sum_{n = 0}^{n = \infty} {I\{S_{n} = 0\}}) < \infty) = 0$. $I$ is indicator. I.e. random walk is returnable if it returns to $0$ infinitely many times almost surely.